# How can I get rid of the warning import/no-anonymous-default-export in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compilation

I get the warning in the consle:"Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export."

This is coming from my .js functions which export several functions as default. I am not sure how to get rid of, while still being able to export several functions as default and keep the code simple as per below.

```
function init() {}

function log(error) {
  console.error(error);
}

export default {
  init,
  log,
};
```

I could write the file as:

```
export default function init() {}

export function log(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Is there a setting I need to change, something I can do about it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's telling you to give the object being exported a *name* before exporting, to make it more likely that the name used is consistent throughout the codebase. For example, change to:

```
function init() {}

function log(error) {
  console.error(error);
}

const logger = {
  init,
  log,
};
export default logger;
```

(Give it whatever name makes most sense in context - `logger` is just an example)

But if you're going to export multiple things, using named exports would make a bit more sense IMO. Another option is to do:

```
export function init() {}

export function log(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

and then import them as:

```
import { init, log } from './foo.js';
```

Comment: And why it's important? Any reason why I should follow this rule in the case of standard web development? I can't remember any situation where I had some issues with the unnamed default export.

Comment: @Velidan The only issue it could cause is with *maintainability*. A code's logic, if implemented properly, will work regardless of whether a name is given to the default export. Putting a default export into a variable beforehand will force you to *give it a name*, giving consumers of the module a convention of what you recommend the import be called. With no hint, the names are liable to become very inconsistent. `myHttpLibrary` or `MyHttpLibrary` or `MyHTTPLibrary` etc. Inadvertent inconsistency is a frequent cause of bugs in programming. Not a huge deal, but that's why there's a lint rule.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification but, to be honest, we usually use 'barreling' or default exporting either in some folder index file or the module itself. Each of them has a naming. For example ```/formik/index.ts``` exporting. We definitely know that it's a formik package. Or  ```/some-folder/Formik.tsx``` - and again we know that it's a formik package because we import it and we see what exactly name it has. Please, fix me if I'm wrong. I just want to understand the reason of this rule

Comment: @Velidan Having an *exact name* to indicate what you're importing is a bit better. `/formik/index.ts` probably isn't enough - `import myFormikPackage`? `import theIndexFormikPackage`? `formik`? `Formik`? Not entirely obvious what it should be. Unless the filename or (if `index.js`) the folder name always exactly matches the export, including capitalization, that's great - that's what I did when using default exports. But that's a bit harder to enforce from a style perspective. It wouldn't be hard to accidentally be inconsistent. That's one of the reasons why I prefer named exports instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you for the detailed explanation. I understood your position

Answer (score 3):

My friends, you can use these rules inside your `.eslintrc.cjs` or `.eslintrc.js` and change them based on your needs.

For example, sometimes you need to export your codes without naming, like `tailwind.config.js`, `postcss.config.js` or `axios` config which are `object`s, in that case, you can use `"allowObject": true`

```
rules: {
   //...
   "import/no-anonymous-default-export": ["error", {
   "allowArray": false,
   "allowArrowFunction": false,
   "allowAnonymousClass": false,
   "allowAnonymousFunction": false,
   "allowCallExpression": false, // backward compatibility -> e.g. export default foo(bar)
   "allowNew": false,
   "allowLiteral": false,
   "allowObject": true
 }]
}
```

**eslint-plugin-import** -> [no-anonymous-default-export](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md)

Answer (score 1):

Asain your data in a variable, then export as default.

//Example

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bertie Yates',
    age: 29,
    image:
      'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-2_ipcjws.jpg',
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Larry Little',
    age: 36,
    image:
      'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Sean Walsh',
    age: 34,
    image:
      'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg',
  },
]
export default data
```

Comment: Can you post the exact warning you're experiencing and how is triggered?